# ydn indexeddb android native browser unable to see database tables

Tags: ydn-db

I have an web app that uses indexeddb and I use YDN as the wrapper. It works on Safari, internet explorer, firefox and Chrome. But when using the native browser on a Samsung Tab 2 it doesn't seem to create the tables or the database. I have managed to debug the device using weinre (remote debugging) I have inspected the resources tab and the database has not been created. But I have another page in my Web App that shows a list of entries in one of the database tables and it shows the entries and the data that is stored. So that tells me I am saving the data. But on inspection unable to view or verify.

```
  db.count('temp').done(function (TempData) {
   alert("DB TEMP Times " + TempData);
```

});

This returns as zero.

Android Version is 4.2.2
Any ideas? or is this a native browser issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ydn.debug.log('ydn.db', 'finest')` to see the log message during database connection. You can also log to div Element by `ydn.debug.log('ydn.db', 'finest', div)`.

Also checkout https://bitbucket.org/ytkyaw/android-todo demo app.

Comment: hi, I have added the code below to test but I can't seem to create the db or view in the native android browser. Am I doing something incorrectly I am using  ydn.db.jquery-0.75.js. In resources under the database no database to view.

Comment: console.log("0");
ydn.debug.log('ydn.db', 'finest')
var db = new ydn.db.Storage('st');
console.log("1");

Comment: also tried ydn.db-dev.js no logging results or database?

Comment: Run some unit test with logging and learn how it work   http://dev.yathit.com/index/demos.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I ran the following link http://dev.yathit.com/test/test_all.html on the android default browser and all the tests failed.

Comment: With android 4.3, some of the test passed. Use `websql` instead of `indexeddb`.

Comment: Android Samsung Browser doesn't seem to support Indexeddb. Will have a look at websql.